# How can I print double quotes in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-ruby

Am trying to bring output like below in AWS console for Cloudwatch metric filter pattern

```
[w1,w2,w3,w4=!"*10.1.1.1*"&&w5=!"*10.1.1.2*"&&w5="*admin*"]
```

for one of my ruby aws sdk script with below function

```
data_of_ips = ["10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2"]

def run_me(data_of_ips)
    :::
    ::: 
    filter_pattern = '[w1,w2,w3,w4!='"*#{data_of_ips[0]*"'&&w4!='"*#{data_of_ips[1]*"',w5="*admin*"]'
```

but in the aws console output I could see the output like below without " (double quotes) for w4.

```
[w1,w2,w3,w4=!*10.1.1.1*&&w4=!*10.1.1.2*&&w5="*admin*"]
```

Please help me out to fix this.

Comment: Your expected output, the code and the shown output all vary. There's `!=` vs. `=!`, `&&w5=` vs. `,w5=` and `w4` vs. `w5`. Besides, the shown `filter_pattern` line would raise a _syntax error_ and thus won't produce any output. Please review your question and correct the mistakes / typos. In its current form, it's hard to tell what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expect?

```rb
data_of_ips = ["10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2"]
def run_me(data_of_ips)
  "[w1,w2,w3,w4!=\"*#{data_of_ips[0]}*\"&&w4!=\"*#{data_of_ips[1]}*\"&&w5=\"*admin*\"]"
end

puts run_me(data_of_ips)
# => [w1,w2,w3,w4!='"*10.1.1.1*"&&w4!="*10.1.1.2*"&&w5="*admin*"]
```

If you want to put variable or script inside a string, I suggest you can use double quote with `#{}` to do that. It's more clear. And the special char like `"` you can just use `\"` to write them.

Comment: but am expecting pattern to be feed in a variable (filter_pattern) 

filter_pattern = '[w1,w2,w3,w4!='"*#{data_of_ips[0]*"'&&w4!='"*#{data_of_ips[1]*"',w5="*admin*"]'

Comment: it's the same solution, you can try to do
`filter_pattern  = "[w1,w2,w3,w4!=\"*#{data_of_ips[0]}*\"&&w4!=\"*#{data_of_ips[1]}*\"&&w5=\"*admin*\"]"`

Comment: No luck, if I introduced backslash  as you mentioned, I got the error as "Invalid metric pattern" could not create metric.

Comment: @Kavitha start by creating a pattern _manually_ that works in AWS as expected. Then, re-create that pattern dynamically using Ruby. Keep comparing the generated pattern to the manual one and fix all differences (you don't need AWS for this step). Once they match, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way:

```
filter_pattern = '[w1,w2,w3,w4!="'"*#{data_of_ips[0]}*"'"&&w4!="'"*#{data_of_ips[1]}*"'"w5="*admin"]'
```

I used `"'"` (double-quotes single-quote double-quotes) and got the expected output below:

```
filter_pattern = '[w1,w2,w3,w4!="*10.1.1.1*"&&w4!="*10.1.1.2*",w5"*admin*"]'
```